# What's the proper way to clean up, notate and define the Hadamard product over a vector space of complex numbers?

Tags: reference-request, proof-writing

I'm not intimately familiar with field theory and the generalizations of vectors space, so I'd like to ask how to properly set up an argument pertaining to multiplying vectors whose elements are complex numbers, but avoiding using so many ellipsis.

What I'd like to do is define a vector space but equip it with a little something extra, the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)). I don't know if this type of vector space or algebra has a name already, but if it does, I'd like to know.

The way I have it now is:

"Let $\mathbb{C}^n$ be an n-dimensional vector space of complex numbers."

First of all, is that the correct way to preface the space of all vectors whose entries are all complex numbers, but of an undetermined and finite dimension?

Basically, the vectors are $c = (c_1,c_2,...,c_n)$ for $c_1,c_2,...,c_n \in \mathbb{C}.$

Next, I go about defining the Hadamard product by saying

"The Hadamard product takes two elements $a,b \in \mathbb{C}^n$ and returns a third vector $c$ with entries $c = (a_1b_1,a_2b_2,...,a_nb_n)$"

This is phrased a little awkwardly, and I keep using "...". Is there a better bookkeeping tactic for vectors of an undetermined dimension? Or, are ellipsis okay in proof writing?

Comment: Ellipsis is fine. An alternative would be, a third vector $c$ whose $i$th entry is $a_ib_i$ for $1\le i\le n$.

Comment: Ellipsis are ok as long as it is clear (as in this case) what goes in between. I think it's the clearest notation for what you want. Perfectly understandable.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know if this type of vector space or algebra has a name already, but if it does, I'd like to know.

You are describing the [product ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_of_rings) of $n$ copies of $\mathbb{C}$.

> "Let $\mathbb{C}^n$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space of complex numbers."  Is that the correct way to preface the space of all vectors whose entries are all complex numbers, but of an undetermined and finite dimension?

The symbols are correct, and make it clear what you mean, but the English is off.  I might say something like "Consider $\mathbb{C}^n$, the (standard) $n$-dimensional vector space over the complex numbers."

- "Consider" indicates that $\mathbb{C}^n$ should be considered identical with the standard notation, rather than (as the computer-scientists might say) a locally-bound variable.
- "Over" indicates that I want $\mathbb{C}$ to be my base field; I'm not looking for some sort other field $k$ such that the standard complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ are an $n$-dimensional vector space over $k$.

> I keep using "...". Is there a better bookkeeping tactic for vectors of an undetermined dimension? Or, are ellipsis okay in proof writing?

Ellipses are fine, as long as you clarify what the general term is.  Infamously, the sequence "$1,2,4,8,\dots$" can continue ["16"](http://oeis.org/A000079) or ["17"](http://oeis.org/A055545).  (See also: the strong law of small numbers.)

In general, I prefer to just to use an index variable: "The Hadamard product of two vectors $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ is the vector $\vec{z}$ whose $j$<sup>th</sup> component is $z_j=x_jy_j$ (for any $j$)."